# Unresolved reference 'Object'

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I'm trying the following code line:

```
from Object import ClassName
```

and get the error:

> unresolved reference 'Object'

I'm using PyCharm 2.7.3

Comment: How are you running this line of code? Is it part of a larger program?

Comment: No, the line stand alone. I will also mention that I recently installed PyCharm, so maybe my configurations are wrong.

Comment: Is the `Object` module in your `PYTHON_PATH`?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check it?

Answer (score 3):

This is because PyCharm cannot access the object that you are talking about. This is probably because it is not in your `PYTHONPATH`, this may be because you have imported it from a an external library without properly installing the Library.

Also, if you have created an object in a Python file in your directory, then consider importing it like this:

`from .file import Object`